# line chart with values and dates graph iOS

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot, linechart

I have previously used core plot and jawbone line chart view but now I want grid (background) on graph.
[image: This is how I exactly want the graph]

I wanna make exactly like above image any help would be appreciated and also please be specific while posting some third party libs and all.

How can I achieve the above graph (if selected dot/value to show callout) with callout?

Note- In X- axis (dates) and Y- axis (values) are there.

**Edit 1:**
Is it possible to achieve in core plot? If Yes, How and please be specific.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plot space annotation to label the callouts. A simple rounded rectangle shape for the labels is easy—set the `fill`, `borderLineStyle`, and `cornerRadius` of the Core Plot text layer used for the annotation. If you need the little arrow on the side of the annotation, you should be able to draw that by using a stretchable image for the fill.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Eric Skroch. But i want a grid to filled with two different colours as shown above the image.

Comment: Please let me know how to add y-axis inside the graph view. It would be helpful if you suggest or share some sample code example.

Comment: Are you talking about the red fill under each plot? If so, set the `areaFill` for each scatter plot. Use a partially transparent color so the front plot doesn't completely obscure the one behind it.

Comment: Set the `axisLineStyle` to draw the axis line. Make sure it is positioned where it is visible either with the `orthogonalPosition` or with axis constraints. There are examples of both in the *Plot Gallery* example app.